# Escape Commands for " and \

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to send a command that contains file path information in an NSString. The problem I am having is that backslashes used in my string are interpreted as unknown escape characters.

Here is the line:

[myNetwork sendCommand:@"MMEM:STOR:DATA \"INT:\sum_sin.arb\"\n"];

I am receiving warnings about unknown escape commands \s

Does anyone know of a work around?

Thanks,
Hayden

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `\` as escape character, so `\\` for `\` and `\"` for `"`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try \\ for whenever you want to say \